# How to make TeXstudio show console output in its GUI like what TeXworks does?

Tags: texstudio, texworks, output, console

When a file with hundreds of pages starts to be compiled, users will wait for several minutes but the "message" window of TeXstudio does not show the compilation progress bar.

TeXworks shows the compilation progress in its "console output" window.

The question is how to make TeXstudio show console output in its GUI like what TeXworks does.

Comment: I don't know what TeXworks shows (and thus, what you want), but my guess is if you want console output in the "messages" log, there's an option under `Build -> show stdout -> Always`

Comment: ps. you'll need "Show advanced options" checked in the bottom left corner of the Configure TeXstudio dialog window to see the `show stdout` options

Comment: @Troy Thank you very much! Your answer solved the problem. Thank you again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relevant option for showing the "console output" during the compilation is found under

```
Options -> Configure TeXstudio -> Build -> Show stdout -> Always
```

For this option to be visible, you need Show Advanced Options checkbox ticked on the bottom left hand corner of the Config dialog.

[image: options]

---

Then you'll get the console output in the messages log when you compile your document:

[image]

Comment: Is there also a way to see, what the command was? E.g. pdflatex --synctex=1 file.tex. I would like to see the command which is run, when I save my tex files.