# TexStudio can't generate pdf file!

Tags: pdftex, texstudio

I have a simple project that I have to present using LaTeX and the problem is that TexStudio **does not create the pdf file** in the working directory (even though it creates the .tex, .aux and .txt files). I have tried to configure TexStudio, trying different ways to get the pdf file but nothing seems to work. Also, I tried uninstalling and installing again or restoring every option to default but neither did that work. Please help!

Comment: show the contents of the `.log` file that is generated. That will let us tell you why there is no PDF.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Where can I find the log file? In the working directory all I can see is the 3 files I mentioned (.txt, .tex, .aux)

Comment: I installed miktex

Comment: Yes I am sure, I have already done it so many times trying to export the pdf

Comment: then the file will be somewhere but unless you give _some_ information noone will be able to help. If your file is called `myfile.tex` then you can use the standard windows file search to look for `myfile.log`  or `myfile.dvi` or `myfile.pdf` and see where they are, or show the error log from texstudio if it is failing to run latex.

Comment: I am willing to provide information about the problem but I don't know what information to provide. Latex is running. The only problem is that I can't find the pdf file. I will try to search it with the standard way.

Comment: Nope, can't find it. As I said, I think it doesn't even generate it.

Comment: if latex runs then it will always generate a .log file (it may not generate a pdf file) so the log file will be there. if texstudio can not run latex for some reason then it will log an error. So either way you must be able to show a log. I don't use texstudio but this answer shows how to see the output as latex runs, set up that and show what you get https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467633/how-to-make-texstudio-show-console-output-in-its-gui-like-what-texworks-does

Comment: What is in the `.tex` file?